# Is there any way to run selenium in python with cron job

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

I've created a python script that download some file using selenium, something like this.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#file download path 
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : main_directory}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get(panel_link)
```

This script is working fine when I execute it on terminal on my ubuntu 18.04.5 Server.
But when this script run from crontab it always stop execution when loading chromedriver.
I got this error every time, I run this python script via cron.

`Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5`

What I've tried:

````
 1. add python script directly in crontab 
 2. created other script ```runpython.sh``` and then run python script from there.
 3. created an apache server and tried to execute python script from php
````

All above methods were not working correctly.
Please Note that this python script is executing perfectly when I execute directly but It is not working when executed via cron.

cron:

`48 21 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && python3 /root/script/application_file_download.py >> /home/log/cron.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

1. for sanity, add a job that writes something to a log file to ensure your cronjob is setup correctly.

   `* * * * */1 echo $(date)" cronjob ran" >> /home/<user>/cronlogs/logs.log`
2. Note that paths should be absolute paths. CRON restricts PATH to `/bin:/user/bin`. If your command is in a different location, you can provide the full path to your command
3. Check execute permissions on the chromedriver file. Ensure that the user running cronjob has the needed permissions. `ls-l`

Comment: thanks @User202202181041 
I've already checked all your steps, you can also see I've added my crontab command